# onclick link from SSL iframe to parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe, ssl, lightbox

I've hit a problem. I have a lightbox in which a page opens an iframe containing an SSL page on a different domain (for credit card processing). Once the transaction has completed a link is shown. I need this link to break out of the iframe into the lightbox.

Simple I thought. But using `parent.document.location='';` gives me `Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'`, using `parent.location.href` of `window.parent.location.href` gives me `NS_ERROR_DOM_PROP_ACCESS_DENIED: Access to property denied` and obviously `top.location.href` breaks out of the lightbox also. I thought of breaking the page in the link out automatically, but I don't know how to do that without also breaking out of the lightbox. I've googled it but the webs seems dominated by `top.loc...` answers.

Any ideas?

Comment: An option, which isn't fully supported in all browsers, is `window.postMessage` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: Appreciated, but it needs to be cross browser compatible I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure how cross browser compatible you need it to be, but http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern to do this is that you supply different URL's to the 3rd service provider (credit card payment) for the case the payment fails, succeeds, etc upon calling that service.

I don't think you can interact in between frames from different domains through javascript for security reasons

Comment: Ok so failing opening the link itself in the parent window, how do I get a page, on the same domain as the parent, inside an iframe, to break out into the parent when parent and top are not the same?

Comment: I didn't understand this last comment. Maybe you should reformulate your whole question explaining what you're exactly trying to do ? If you're just willing to have link from an iframe open in the same window, and thus replacing the whole content (parent + iframe) , the target="top" on the link should be enough...

Comment: No because target=top will break it out of the lightbox also! I'm not trying to interact with the parent from the iframe, just open a link from the iframe in the parent, without closing the lighbox, so top is out of the question as far as I can see.

Comment: So you need to load a different content into the lightbox ? Sorry but I don't understand your question actually...

Comment: Ok. Sorry. The link in the iframe needs to break out of the iframe but not the lightbox. I can edit it all as I'm doing it through an API, not a third party as such. If it is simpler I can make the end page (the one the link goes to and which is on the same domain as the lightbox) break out of the iframe automatically rather than try and edit the link... as in have the link open in the iframe as the normal behaviour would do and then automatically break out of the iframe. I can do this normally but I don't know how to only break out of the iframe and not the lightbox also.